# Select specific content of an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have built a QRCode Scanner app, and i want to select specific content of the Code's value. At the moment I store the value of the QRCode as an array and I use it as the user's input. At a second step i would like to take half of the array's contents and use them as the first input, and then take the rest of the array and use it as the second input. As you can see the inPut (EditText) uses the whole array as an input.

i.e. There will be inPut1 & inPut2. The QRcode's value is "user@user.com qwerty12345". So inPut1 = "user@user.com" and inPut2 = "qwerty12345".

Excuse me for any mistakes in this question but I'm a new user in StackOverflow's community. Any advice/help will be accepted!

my method below:

```java
 @Override
 public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
    final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
    if (qrcodes.size() != 0)
    {
      txtResult.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Vibration
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(600);
        txtResult.setText(qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
        inPut.setText(qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
        }


     });
 }
```

}

Comment: Where is inPut defined? Post your whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
  @Override
     public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
        final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
        if (qrcodes.size() != 0)
        {
          txtResult.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            //Vibration
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(600);
            String value=qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
            txtResult.setText(value.split(" ")[0]);
            inPut.setText(value.split(" ")[1]);
            }
          });
     }
```

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) for more information.

Hope, it helps!!

Comment: Thank you! That work exactly as i wanted. i Just created a second inPut named inPut2 because i need txtResult to print the value of QRCode also.

Comment: Glad to help you !!